# Why are multiple rotate() needed to place every number on the right spot? - Canvas Clock Numbers

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Following [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_clock.asp) which shows how to make an analog clock using HTML canvas, I've had a hard time understanding what is going on [when placing numbers on the clock face.](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_clock_numbers.asp)

The code is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trycanvas_clock_numbers), and the following is the part that I'd like to ask.

```
function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";

  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}
```

In a for loop, the first `ctx.rotate(ang)` sets the number on the place it's supposed to be.

The next rotate `ctx.rotate(-ang)` puts the number back to upright because it's tilted. (although I don't know why it works like this not putting the number back to the first position.)

Then, after `ctx.fillText(…)` shows the number up, it seems to do the same again.

Why are these two `rotate()` needed? Do they work differently from the ones in the upper? If do, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this code tries to do is to go back to its previous position, the center of the canvas.

Think of the context as a sheet of paper that you can rotate and move (`translate`), with a fixed pen over it.

- First they do rotate that sheet of paper so that tracing a vertical line will go in the desired direction.
- Then they move the sheet of paper vertically, so that the pen is at the correct position. However here, the sheet of paper is still rotated, so if they were to draw the text horizontally from here, the drawing would be oblique.
- So they do rotate again in the other way for the text to be at correct angle.
- They draw the text.
- Now they want to go back to point 1 to be able to draw the next tick. For this they do the same route but in the other way: rotate back the sheet of paper to the desired angle so that they can move vertically to the center.
- Move vertically to the center
- Finally rotate back so that the sheet of paper is in its original orientation for the next tick.

However **you should not do this.** `rotate()` may end up having rounding issues, so doing `rotate(angle); rotate(-angle)` can not come back to the initial orientation, but to some slightly rotated state, which can be catastrophic for your application since now when you'll try to draw pixel perfect lines, you won't be able and you will kill the whole performances of your app.

Instead use the absolute [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) method to go back to the original position:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
radius = radius * 0.90
drawNumbers(ctx, radius);

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    // go (back) to center
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, radius, radius);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
  }
  // reset to identity matrix;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">
</canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Now, I can't get the first rotate.
I believe it rotates clockwise and it seems number 1 will be placed on number 11 point...

I tried to understand the concept using a square sticky note and the pen fixed on the center of the note.
What did I misunderstand now?

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion, it's actually the drawing tools that are rotated not the sheet of paper, so the rotate acts as the inverse for the sheet of paper. Like for the first translate(radius radius), it will move the pen from top left corner to the center, the transformation is inversed too if we take the sheet of paper as referential.

Comment: I've written the article about this and I'm still not sure very much if my understanding is correct.  If you could check this, I'd appreciate it!
https://dev.to/shivchan/the-mystery-of-rotate-method-in-html-canvas-2aoa

Comment: @Kaho yes sounds right to me, your explanation is clearer than mine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another implementation without using rotate.
Instead I calculate the `x, y` with a bit of trigonometry.

The starting angle is `var ang = Math.PI;`
Then in the loop we decrease it `ang -= Math.PI / 6;`

Calculating the position is easy once you know the formula:

```
let x = radius * Math.sin(ang)
let y = radius * Math.cos(ang)
```

Below is a fully functional example

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
ctx.font = "16px arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";

var radius = 60
var ang = Math.PI;

for (let num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
  ang -= Math.PI / 6;
  let x = radius * Math.sin(ang)
  let y = radius * Math.cos(ang)

  ctx.fillText(num.toString(), x, y);
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(x, y - 6, 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();  
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(x, y - 6, 45, -ang-2,-ang);
  ctx.stroke();  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="160"></canvas>
```

I personally never been a fan of using rotate, for a small static canvas image might be fine, but as we move to more complex animations with multiple object, when I have to debug with multiple rotation it quickly becomes painful and quite hard to follow.